# Sum only certain values of an array based on a condition pyspark

Tags: arrays, pyspark, sum, conditional-statements, aggregate

I would like to create a column that is based on the sum of array values. However, if the sum would exceed a target value, it would only sum the values that create the highest value under or equal to the target.  Here is an example:

```
| Target % | Array            | name      | Total
| ---------| -----------------|-----------|----------
| 4.5      | [1.5,2.5,3.0,2.0]| John      | 4.5
| 3        | [2.5,1.0,0.5,1.0]| Jim       | 3.0
| 5        | [1.0,1.0,1.5,1.0]| Jane      | 4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if the sum would exceed a target value, it would only sum the values that create the highest value under or equal to the target.

To find the highest sum of values that is `<=` than the target you'll have to find sums of different combinations of values and then find the suitable value.

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from itertools import combinations
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, StringType, StructField, StructType


def find_highest(values, target):
    if not values:
        return None
    values.sort()
    max_value = values[0]
    if max_value > target:
        return None
    if max_value == target:
        return max_value
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        if values[i] <= target and values[i] > max_value:
            max_value = values[i]
    return max_value


def find_closest_sum(numbers, target):
    target = float(target)
    if sum(numbers) <= target:
        return sum(numbers)
    results = []
    for n in range(1, len(numbers) + 1):
        sumlist = [sum(l) for l in combinations(numbers, n)]
        highest = find_highest(sumlist, target)
        if highest:
            results.append(highest)
    return find_highest(results, target)


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"Target": "4.5", "Array": [1.5, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0]},
    {"Target": "3", "Array": [2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0]},
    {"Target": "5", "Array": [1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0]},
    {"Target": "7", "Array": [5.0, 1.0, 4.0]},
]
schema = StructType(
    [StructField("Target", StringType()), StructField("Array", ArrayType(DoubleType()))]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df = df.withColumn("Total", F.udf(find_closest_sum)(F.col("Array"), F.col("Target")))
```

Result:

```
+------+--------------------+-----+                                             
|Target|Array               |Total|
+------+--------------------+-----+
|4.5   |[1.5, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0]|4.5  |
|3     |[2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0]|3.0  |
|5     |[1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0]|4.5  |
|7     |[5.0, 1.0, 4.0]     |6.0  |
+------+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  This is the error I get from using this suggestion: 
A NoneType object does not have an attribute _jvm. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.

I'm wondering if it has to do with this line:

df = df.withColumn("Total", F.udf(find_closest_sum)(F.col("Array"), F.col("Target")))
                                                                                 ^

Is that parenthesis supposed to be there? Additionally, the Target column is a double, not a string, so I took the float conversion line out. With these changed, errors are:

Comment: line 701, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: df = df.withColumn("Total", F.udf(find_closest_sum)(F.col("Array"), F.col("Target")))  The parenthesis I am referring to is the one after F.udf(find_closest_sum) <-

Comment: @AlexTriece I'm not sure how you are running the code. Yes, the parenthesis should be there, it defines a function that takes columns as arguments. Could you please confirm that you can run the code I provided and that it works as is (just the code I gave), after that we can debug why it doesn't work in your setting.

Comment: I have run the code, however I did not run this section: 

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"Target": "4.5", "Array": [1.5, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0]},
    {"Target": "3", "Array": [2.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0]},
    {"Target": "5", "Array": [1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0]},
    {"Target": "7", "Array": [5.0, 1.0, 4.0]},
]
schema = StructType(
    [StructField("Target", StringType()), StructField("Array", ArrayType(DoubleType()))]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

as I am performing this on an already existing dataframe.

Comment: I get this error:  A NoneType object does not have an attribute _jvm

Comment: I place the two functions in a global code area, and run the df = df.withColumn("Total", F.udf(find_closest_sum)(F.col("Array"), F.col("Target"))) portion separately.

Comment: Something in your input dataset is not right. I don't know what because you haven't provided it. Please confirm that it works when you include only the code from my example. After that continue to debug for your input dataset or provide more information on what you are exactly doing.

Comment: Im sorry, I'm not sure what you are wanting.  i was trying to paste in a sample of the data I am using.  Is there something else you were asking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239402/discussion-between-vlad-siv-and-alex-triece).

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are saying, not ignoring. I am using a very particular web based ide, for my workplace only, so often the code here doesnt translate exactly to my framework.  Trying to learn how to make it work here. I will continue on my own for now, unless you have any other suggestions off the bat.